# Bottom align image in one paragraph with text in last paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

CURRENT HTML/CSS

```css
img{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
div{
position:relative
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>
    first paragraph text first paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph paragraph text paragraph text paragraph first text paragraph
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    2nd paragraph text 2nd paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text paragraph text 2nd paragraph text 
  </p>
  
  <p>
    3rd paragraph text 3rd paragraph text paragraph text 3rd paragraph
  </p>
  
</div>
```

I'm stuck on an HTML page with three paragraphs, the 2nd paragraph contains an image, 
I need to bottom left align that image with the text in the 3rd paragraph 
(say the last paragraph) without increasing the vertical distance between each paragraph. 
This may push a few lines of the first paragraph towards the right but it's fine.

I've tried using float and `{position:absolute;bottom:0 with position:relative on div tag}` with no success as the text is not flowing around the image.

Is it possible to do this with CSS/JS without changing the HTML?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, maybe include illustration or image of your final result expectation.

Comment: Thank you very much, What I want is make the text flow around the image,

Comment: img {float: right} // without positioning

Comment: with only float image won't bottom align with the last paragraph

Comment: Have you tried float:left for img and float:right for p:last-child?

Comment: Thank you all for your response, in the end this code worked for me https://codepen.io/kaleemullah/pen/deaMWE